# ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG Wordpress/Chrome

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

I'm running into this problem where Chrome is responding with the **ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG** when I try to visit my WordPress instance. I use htop to monitor the server and I see sharp spikes in MySQL and Apache memory consumption as well once the request is made. Finally, if I try to access the site using incognito mode, the site response normally and the error disappear. I looked around and found other related and suggested solutions like **LimitRequestFieldSize 4094** and **LimitRequestLine 4094** to restrict the header size, but with no luck. My environment is as follows:

WordPress version 4.8

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

uname -r
4.4.0-59-generic

apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

php --version
PHP 7.1.5-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
```

Comment: Can you see what's in the header in the Chrome dev tools?

Comment: Actually I just solved it. After declaring the new limits as mentioned above, I had to clear all data and manually delete all site related stored cookies in my browser. Now its working perfectly again.